# How do I undo a tortoisesvn update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to retrieve my working copy of a file before updating to a new revision. The problem is somehow tortoise messed things up and now a days work worth of code is uncompilable.

I tried updating to the previous revision, yet I got so many conflicts that I cannot fix since SVn literally merged all the text together.

Does Tortoise SVN versions a file locally before doing an update, and where can I find the file. I tried looking under .svn\prestine but I could only find an old version of my code.

Can someone please help.

Comment: I don't this it is possible to recover earlier contents in such case. I am also curious to know if there is any way to do this as this has happened to me some times.

Comment: @AnilSoman: There are version control systems that can do it. Use one as subversion client.

Comment: Do you have any .mine files? When there is a merge conflict, Tortoise SVN usually creates both a .mine and a .theirs alongside the merged conflicted file.

Comment: I doubt that Tortoise itself corrupted your files. What is more likely is that you merged in changes (via the update) which someone else had made, which then made the whole thing uncompilable. It's also possible, as Matthew Strawbridge points out, that there are unresolved merge conflicts. In either case, you really should just resolve the problems (see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) and [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html), not fall back. Tortoise does not keep intermediate versions locally.

Comment: I think the problem was from SVN merge, it did show me some conflicts when I first updates, but I edited them and marked the files as resolved. Problme is  that somewhow I have pargraphs after paragraphs of codes with overlapping words. Lucky me, I kept the svn conflicts editor open. Just took the (mine) panel and replaced the file. I cant believe I did not notice that before posting the question

Comment: I think uncompilable is just sugar coating the issue I had. The thing is that when I viewed the file after the update it was messed in a way that I swear I had paragraphs of code with meshed words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to do it. You are out of luck.

The way I solved it is using [git](http://git-scm.com) as subversion client. Git is significantly different from subversion and the subversion interaction adds some restrictions of it's own, but it gives you better protection from loosing work to merge conflicts.

Plus it has support for committing individual changes separately and keeping a local stack of changes, which I often use if I find a bug during some larger task and want to push it out to trunk while the main work is still in progress or if I want to separate the work to logical pieces that are easier to check.